# Excel Formula Checking multiple cells across the columns

Tags: excel, formula

I would like a formula that compare the column B, D, F and puts in Column H if a computer has only office 2007 or both 2007 & 2010 or 2007 and 2013, etc... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Excel Layout for Question:
[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53308529/edit) to let us know what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),2007,"")&" "&IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D2)),2010,"")&" "&IF(NOT(ISBLANK(F2)),2013,""),"  "," ")
```

If you know the exact values that will appear in columns `B`, `D` and `F`, you can try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IF(B2="Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2007",2007,"")&" "&IF(D2="Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010",2010,"")&" "&IF(F2="Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013",2013,""),"  "," ")
```

Comment: I think maybe close, but weather the cell is blank or not it just shows in Column H 2007 2010 2013 regardless if something in the cell or not.

Comment: Are you sure the cell is blank and doesn't contain a space or other invisible character?

Comment: I am pulling from another sheet, and I am putting nothing there but probably not "blank"  how get around that?  Example B2 has a vlookup arrary  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'2007'!A:F,{5,6},FALSE),"")